# Need help understanding problem alternating visibility of a DIV by dynamically switching classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visibility

This code attempts to dynamically switch the class of the StateContainer div from StateOne to StateTwo to alternate the visibility of the DIV.

When I run it, I always see the following both before and after clicking the button.

```
Visible first
Visible first
Visible first
Visible first
```

Would appreciate any suggestions for why this code does not work the way I'm expecting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.StateOne .InitiallyHidden { display: none; }
.StateTwo .InitiallyVisible { display: none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

    $('.x').click(
       var s = document.GetElementById('StateContainer');
       s.className = (s.className == 'StateOne' ? 'StateTwo' : 'StateOne');
    );

    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<button class="x">Change StateContainer</button>

<div class="StateOne" id="StateContainer">
   <div class="InitiallyVisible">Visible first</div>
   <div class="InitiallyHidden">Visible second</div>
   <div class="InitiallyVisible">Visible first</div>
   <div class="InitiallyHidden">Visible second</div>
   <div class="InitiallyVisible">Visible first</div>
   <div class="InitiallyHidden">Visible second</div>
   <div class="InitiallyVisible">Visible first</div>
   <div class="InitiallyHidden">Visible second</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not using the `click` event properly. You need to provide it with a function:

```
$('.x').click(function() {
       var s = document.getElementById('StateContainer');
       s.className = (s.className == 'StateOne' ? 'StateTwo' : 'StateOne');
});
```

Also, if you're already using jQuery, the following syntax is much shorter than `document.getElementById` (which doesn't have a capital G, by the way):

```
var s = $("#StateContainer")[0];
```

Steve

Comment: Thank you . . . Head scratching comes to an end.

Comment: Cool. That's a nice shorthand syntax.

Comment: Oops. Spoke to soon - I added your shorthand form - var s = $("#StateContainer"); and it stopped working. Are you sure you wrote that right?

Comment: Weird. According to the jQuery docs, it should work: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/id#id.

Comment: Oh, perhaps this doesn't *return* the element... perhaps they expect you to use it like "$("#StateContainer").doSomething()"... I'll keep looking quickly through the jQuery docs...

Comment: Yep. I have a feeling it's just for chained method calls. Interesting. Thanks for the link.

Comment: It stops working because doing $('#StateContainer') returns a wrapped set, not the native element you are using. If you refer to it as s[0].className it would work.

Comment: @Paolo Bergantino: Thanks! I've updated my answer accordingly.